# .NET MAUI: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, .net-7.0

I have created a ResourceDictionary file that comes with a *.cs* file. So after creating the ResourceDictionary file I'm getting an error:

> The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Below is the XAML file associated with the above file.

[image]

I'm using VS2022 17.5.0 Preview 1.0

1. I have set the build action for the C# file to C# Compiler
2. I have cleaned and rebuilt my project several times and tried deleting the *bin* and *obj* folders, but nothing seems to work

Comment: What's the build action for the XAML file?

Comment: MauiXAML is the build action for the xaml file

Comment: Was the `InitializeComponent` call something you added? I don't know MAUI well, but might it be that `ResourceDictionaries` don't generate an `InitializeComponent` method?

Comment: InitializeComponent is generated when I create the file, I did not add the function

Comment: Even though VS puts this in the code view, does your solution actually build?

Comment: No it doesn't build because of the posted error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I do `Project / rt-click / Add / NewItem / .Net Maui ResourceDictionary (XAML)`, this is what gets added to .csproj:

```xml
<MauiXaml Update="Dictionary1.xaml"> 
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
</MauiXaml>
```

Note that the `Compile` is nested within the `MauiXaml` element; it is not a separate Item.

See if your .csproj has TWO separate Items, one for `Dictionary1.xaml`, another for `Dictionary1.xaml.cs`.

If so, replace those two items, with a combined item as shown above.

(For me, this builds without problem.)

---

In your case, the .csproj doesn't show `MauiXaml` BuildAction?

Replace:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="Themes\Light.xaml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

with:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <MauiXaml Update="Themes\Light.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
</ItemGroup>
```

I don't know whether this should be kept or removed:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="Themes\" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Leave it in for now.

Comment: For me this is what gets added on the csproj file:                                    
        <ItemGroup>
   <None Include="Themes\Light.xaml" />
 </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
   <Folder Include="Themes\" />
 </ItemGroup>

Comment: Added more to answer.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a similar issue that often plagues Xamarin solutions. I think that there's an underlying bug, or delay in interpreting the files when displayed within Visual Studio.

Several options:

- Make a small change to the file in question - even adding or deleting a space will do, save it and rebuild solution.
- Clean the solution and rebuild.
- Unload and reload project to which the files belong. (Right click on the project in Solution explorer window, select unload, then select load.
- Xaml files may need to be set as embedded resource as their Build Action under their properties (again in Solution explorer).

Comment: None of the metioned steps seems to work for me

Answer (score -1):

My ultimate solution:
Uninstall VS and all versions of .Net Framework and SDK and .Core
Restart PC
Install VS 2022 again with **only default settings**, without selecting additional packages.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).